Spring @DateTimeFormat exception when reading POST parameters
I am sending this string representation of date Apr 15, 2024, 12:00:21 PM as a POST parameter. I am trying to read it into Spring MVC @RequestMapping method like below:
public void updateRecord(@RequestParam("dateAdded") 
                         @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss aa") Date dateAdded){

}

I get following exception:
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "Apr 15, 2024, 12:00:21 PM"]]

What am I doing wrong?

Can you please show how you are firing the request?

With that pattern it seems that you will want to use the modern LocalDateTime type instead of the outdated Date. Beware of time zone issues, though. If there is any way you can, avoid the Date class. It had design problems and has been outdated for 10 years.

For me it works, use the following
spring.web.locale=US

Also, this locale can be overridden by the "Accept-Language" header.

Where in the app does the spring.web.locale go?

in the application.properties file
